# Select last values based on rows below in another column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been working on a dataset with rolling subs for a netball game. I'm trying to find the last 5 players to be left on the bench, but there is another column where players swap on. This causes issues as a player could sub off in the last 5 rows then sub back on later, so I can't simply use tail(5). So if the player swaps back on, then effectively she isn't the last on the bench. Here's a dataframe below, with the last 8 values.

| sub_off | sub_on | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alexia | Jorja | 750 |
| **Amy** | Sophie | 770 |
| **Jorja** | Cassandra | 800 |
| **Lucy** | Jane | 820 |
| Claire | Khloe | 820 |
| **Cassie** | Alexia | 850 |
| Khloe | Claire | 890 |
| **Georgia** | Khloe | 895 |

Notice I want to pick the 5 players that remain on the bench. These would be Georgia, Cassie, Lucy, Jorja and Amy. This is because Khloe, Claire and Alexia sub back on later in the game.

**In other words, I want to pick the last 5 values in the sub_off column that don't appear in the rows following for the sub_on column**.

```
df <- data.frame(
  sub_off = c('Alexia', 'Amy', 'Jorja', 'Lucy', 'Claire', 'Cassie', 'Khloe', 'Georgia'),
  sub_on = c('Jorja', 'Sophie', 'Cassandra', 'Jane', 'Khloe', 'Alexia', 'Claire', 'Khloe'),
  time = c(750, 770, 800, 820, 820, 850, 890, 895)
)
df
```

Here's the dataframe, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *data.table* option using an anti-join between `sub_off` and `sub_on` where the `time` is later:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[!df, on=c("sub_off"="sub_on","time<time"), .(bench=sub_off)]
#     bench
#1:     Amy
#2:   Jorja
#3:    Lucy
#4:  Cassie
#5: Georgia
```

Comment: Claire is supposed to be somewhere there I think. I'm assuming greater time means later in the game.

Comment: Nope, Claire subs back on at 890 and doesn't sub off again.

Comment: Just wondering, why doesn't she show up in the df in the sub-in category?

Comment: @JahiZamy - the `sub_on` column here is pretty meaningless, it's just the `sub_off` that is the key output - i'll drop the other columns.

Comment: I know I get it. I was just wondering how DT works, never used the package.

Comment: `basetable[(!=remove)jointable, on=.(match-sub_off-to-sub_on, match-basetable.time<jointable.time)]` - so i'm seeing if there is a match from a sub-off to a later sub-on, and then removing those records from the output. I think this will work generally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Doesn't seem to work on my end but I'll get it to work. Just curious if there's any possibly dplyr solution to this, by filtering or rather?